# PySpark UDF to return tuples of variable sizes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I take an existing Dataframe and create a new one with a field containing tuples. A UDF is used to produce this field. For instance, here, I take a source tuple and modify its elements to produce a new one:

```
udf( lambda x: tuple([2*e for e in x], ...)
```

The challenge is that the tuple's length is not known in advance and can change from row to row.

From what I understand reading related discussions, to return a tuple, UDF's return type has to be declared as StructType. However, since the number of elements in the returned tuple is not known, I can't just write something like:

```
StructType([
    StructField("w1", IntegerType(), False),
    StructField("w2", IntegerType(), False),
    StructField("w3", IntegerType(), False)])
```

It appears that it is possible to return lists, but lists wouldn't work for me, since I need a hashable object in the output Dataframe.

What are my options?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StructType` / `Row` represents fixed sized [product type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_type) object and cannot be used to represent objects of variable size.

To represent homogeneous collections use `list` as external type, and `ArrayType` as SQL type:

```
udf(lambda x: [2*e for e in x], ArrayType(IntegerType()))
```

or (Spark 2.2 or later):

```
udf(lambda x: [2*e for e in x], "array<integer>")
```

In Spark 2.4 or later you can use `transform`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

expr("tranform(input_column, x -> 2 * x)")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. ArrayType() works. 
Unlike regular Python arrays/lists, ArrayType appears to be hashable. 
Are there any issues (primarily  speed) one needs to be aware of when using this type as a key for join() and other Dataframe and SQL operations?

Comment: In general complex structures are hard to work with, and only some operations can be expressed using native functions. The rest will require `udf`, which is expensive, especially in Python.

Answer (score 0):

New syntax per Databricks (Spark) for one row at time (syntax more in line with Pandas UDF which seem to be where udfs are going in python https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html):

One row-at-time:

```
@udf(ArrayType(IntegerType()))
def new_tuple(x):
    return [2*e for e in x]
```